# Is it possible to get the equisatisfiable boolean formula of a QF_UF formula using existing SMT solvers?

Tags: z3, smt, satisfiability

In eager SMT solvers, a SMT formula is encoded as a equisatisfiable boolean formula which is fed to a SAT solver. Typically, for QF_UF formulae, uninterpreted functions are reduced by Ackermann's reduction or Bryant's reduction, and then a equisatisfiable boolean formula is constructed by equality graph approach.

So I want to know if it is possible to invoke an existing SMT solver to get the equisatisfiable boolean formula given a QF_UF formula without hacking the low-level implementation of the solver. For example, Z3 has some tactics to transform the input problem (such as `tseitin-cnf` and `elim-term-ite`), and is there a tactic for such translation?

Answer (score 2):

In z3 you can dump DIMACS with a patch like https://gist.github.com/nunoplopes/8cd9fb433b2663c99cb34c8a95ae812f

You can also use the bit-blast tactic to get the SAT formula, which will be over Boolean Z3 variables. I don't think that's guaranteed to be in CNF or NNF or whatever form.

Comment: I will try the first solution later. For the second one, when I attempt to apply `bit-blast` tactic to a QF_UF problem ([link](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/hWVI)), the output is still a QF_UF problem. Did I do something wrong or `bit-blast` tactic only supports BV problem?

Comment: Ah, yes. You need to get rid of the UF symbols first.
There's now an Ackermannization tactic. The name is ackermannize_bv IIRC.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now UF symbols are reduced. But I found that `bit-blast` is still not working for converting QF_UF problem to SAT formula ([example](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/MSfEo)). So is there any working tactic to translate a QF_UF formula without uninterpreted functions of non-zero arity to SAT formula? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by a SAT formula?  If you want DIMACS you need to use the patch I've provided; I don't think that functionality is exposed.

Comment: If you want CNF or NNF, there are also tactics for that.

Comment: Sorry my question may be confusing. What I want to do is to transform equality logic to propositional logic. So the lazy solvers such as Z3 do not expose such functionality, right?